# Call to undefined function printf __()

Tags: php, wordpress

I got this error on my Page

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function printf__() in /home/register/public_html/wp-content/themes/rmm-store/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php on line 59

See line 59 highlighted below (with `offending line` comment):

```
<tr class="order">
  <td class="order-number">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg('order', $order->id, get_permalink( woocommerce_get_page_id( 'view_order' ) ) ) ); ?>">
      <?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>
    </a>
  </td>
  <td class="order-date">
    <time datetime="<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>
  </td>
  <td class="order-status" style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;">
    /* offending line 59 */  <?php echo ucfirst( printf__( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), $status->name ); ?>
  </td>
  <td class="order-total">
    <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>
  </td>
```

Comment: Line 59 is the line with 3 ***

Comment: Possibly useful information at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57197/how-does-printf-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__()` operator in Wordpress is for [i18n or internationalization](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). This works fine, but the printf is incorrectly structured and therefore throws the error, it's a simple fix, but you should be no means omit the `__()` if you have a multilingual site.

Straight from the documentation:

*The solution is to use the printf family of functions. Especially helpful are printf and sprintf. Here is what the right solution of the spams count problem will look like:*

Therefore, proper implementation is as follows:

```
printf(__( '%s', 'woocommerce' ), $status->name ));
```